How to use pandoc for converting a markdown to pdf (Persian and English)
I have a markdown file to Persian and English.
How can I use pandoc for convert it to pdf?
I use it
pandoc Manual.md --pdf-engine=xelatex -o Manual.pdf

and pandoc output is
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ق (U+0642) (U+0642) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=t


This question is similar to: How to convert Markdown to PDF (with word wrapping). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can use Marker to do it with GUI.
Install Marker with
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/marker
sudo apt update
sudo apt install marker

Open the Markdown file with Marker, and click on hamberger menu -> Export. Then, export it as PDF.

